# predict function not evaluating for all given points with F# R-type-provider

Tags: r, f#

I am converting a small code snippet to F# using the [R type provider](https://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/). Everything works fine and evaluates, however I cannot seem to make the predict function use all the points I give it for its prediction.

The R code snippet:

```
Nit = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6) 
AOB = c(4.26,4.15,4.68,6.08,5.87,6.92,6.87,6.25,6.84,6.34,6.56,6.52,7.39,7.38,7.74,7.76,8.14,7.22)
AOBm=tapply(AOB,Nit,mean) #means of AOB 
Nitm=tapply(Nit,Nit,mean) #means of Nit 
fitAOB=lm(AOBm∼ns(Nitm,df=2)) #natural spline
predict(fitAOB,data.frame(Nitm=seq(xmin,xmax,.5))
```

and the coresponding F# code:

```ml
let Nit = [0;0;0;1;1;1;2;2;2;3;3;3;4;4;4;6;6;6]
let AOB = [4.26;4.15;4.68;6.08;5.87;6.92;6.87;6.25;6.84;6.34;6.56;6.52;7.39;7.38;7.74;7.76;8.14;7.22]

let AOBm = R.tapply(AOB,Nit, "mean")
let Nitm = R.tapply(Nit, Nit, "mean")

let fitAOB = 
    namedParams [
        "AOBm", box AOBm 
        "Nitm", box Nitm 
    ]
    |> R.data_frame
    |> fun d -> R.lm(formula="AOBm~splines::ns(Nitm,df=2)", data=d)

let xmin, xmax = float(List.min Nit), float(List.max Nit)

let prediction1 = 
    namedParams [ "Nitm",[xmin .. 0.5 .. xmax]]
    |> R.data_frame
    |> fun data -> R.predict(fitAOB, data)

prediction1.Print()
```

The R code snippet gives me following for the prediction:

```ml
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
4.753486 5.177103 5.590795 5.984636 6.348702 6.673067 6.947806 7.166302 
       9       10       11       12       13 
7.335171 7.464340 7.563733 7.643276 7.712893
```

And the F# code snippet gives me following for the prediction:

```ml
val it : string =
  "       0        1        2        3        4        6 
4.753486 5.668817 6.470509 7.048984 7.388006 7.660199 
"
```

**What am I missing?, eg. why doesn't the predict function take all the [0.0 .. 0.5 .. 6.0] points into account when predicting?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make R.predict yield the same result as the predict function used from within R.

```
let prediction1 = 
    namedParams [ 
        "type",box "prediction"
        "Nitm",box [0.0 .. 0.5 .. 6.0]
    ]
    |> R.data_frame
    |> fun d -> R.predict(fitAOB, [0.0 .. 0.5 .. 6.0], d)
prediction1.Print()
```

which gives

```
val it : string =
  "       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
4.753486 5.177103 5.590795 5.984636 6.348702 6.673067 6.947806 7.166302 
       9       10       11       12       13 
7.335171 7.464340 7.563733 7.643276 7.712893 
"
```

However, I don't quite understand why I have to repeat the [0.0 .. 0.5 .. 6.0] sequence..